Find $a$ such that $a^3 + 1$ is a multiple of $b-a$
I am working on the following question but I cannot solve it.

Let $a$ and $b$ be two consecutive square numbers with $a<b$. If $a^3
 + 1$ is a multiple of $b-a$, find the greatest possible value of $a$.

My attempt:
Let $a = n^2$ and $b = (n+1)^2$ for some integer $n$. Hence, $b-a = 2n+1$.
Since $a^3 + 1$ is a multiple of $b-a$, we conclude that $\frac{a^3 + 1}{b-a}=\frac{n^6 + 1}{2n+1}$ is an integer. By long division, we have
$$\frac{n^6 + 1}{2n+1} = \frac{1}{2}n^5-\frac14n^4+\frac18n^3-\frac{1}{16}n^2+\frac{1}{32}n-\frac{1}{64}+\frac{65}{64(2n+1)}.$$
Note that the above must be an integer. By observing the first five terms of the quotient, we can say that $n$ must be a multiple of $32$. I am not sure what to do next. Any help is appreciated.

$n$ is not just a multiple of $32$, it is $32$. If you look at the last term of the quotient you got, you have $2n+1 | 65$, and you already have $32 | n$. Hence, $n=32$ which gets you $a$

@AkshajMishra : I was tricked by the question and I thought 'greatest possible' means there can be more than 1 value of $n$. So I was wondering if I should also consider the term $-\frac{1}{64}$ to find more answers.

$$
\frac{n^6 + 1}{2n+1}
= \frac{1}{2}n^5-\frac14n^4+\frac18n^3-\frac{1}{16}n^2+\frac{1}{32}n-\frac{1}{64}+\frac{65}{64(2n+1)}
= \frac{1}{64}\left(32n^5-16n^4+8n^3-4n^2+2n-1+\frac{65}{2n+1}\right)
$$
Clearly, the expression in the brackets must be a multiple of $64$ (and hence an integer) for the R.H.S. to be an integer.
Since $32n^5-16n^4+8n^3-4n^2+2n-1$ is an integer, $\frac{65}{2n+1}$ must also be an integer, and so $2n+1 \mid 65$ is necessary.
$65=13 \cdot 5$, so we have $2n+1=13$, $2n+1=5$ or $2n+1=65$. These give us $n=6$, $n=2$ and $n=32$ respectively. If we test these values in the initial expression $\frac{n^6+1}{2n+1}$, it does indeed work.
This leads to $a=36$, $a=4$ and $a=1024$. The correct answer (greatest value of $a$) is thus $1024$.
Note that your conclusion that $n$ must be a multiple of $32$ is not necessarily correct: it is not necessary that $\frac{1}{32}n$ be an integer, and neither is it necessary for any of those terms to be integers; it matters only that their sums evaluate to an integer in the end. The reason we can say with certainty that $32n^5-16n^4+8n^3-4n^2+2n-1$ is an integer is because addition, multiplication and subtraction of integers produces only integers, whereas division can produce non-integer rational numbers.

As an aside, as long as $2n+ 1 \mid n^6 + 1$, we will have that the expression in the brackets is a multiple 64 without having to check, which is why when you tested them, they all worked. $\quad$ Easiest way to see that is $ 64 ( n^6 + 1 ) = (2n+1) ( EXP)$. Since $ 2 \not \mid 2n+1$, hence $ 64 \mid EXP$.
